# conceptual question - Don't Repeat your self problem/issue

Tags: oop, dry

I bet we've all done this before.

We have Three functions:

AddCustomer

EditCustomer

DeleteCustomer

Before you can get the data to do add, edit or delete, you must check if the user is allowed to do show, edit or delete.

so you add some calls to some functions at the top of your add, edit and delete customer functions

They are all equal and so ... you are repeating your self (breaking the DRY principle)

My gut feeling tells me there must be a pattern for this.

I also think there is a level here - like this:

remark: btw - not using a programming language here, if it looks like c#, Java, python, pascal (any flavour), php, cobol, fortran, basic (any flavour). It is accidental

```
level 0:
Controller -> request (add/edit/delete)
function() 
call CanUserCreateOrModify() 

Layer 1:
CanUserCreateOrModify-

Layer 2: 
AddCustomer, EditCustomer, DeleteCustomer
```

Not sure which pattern it is though. And I understand at some level there will be some repetition

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its an abstract question about software design and not a specific programming question within the scope defined in the [help/on-topic]. See [Is a question about design patterns too opinionated for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256663/11082165).You may be able to ask this question on [Software Engineering StackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), but be sure to check their content guidelines center before posting

Answer (score 0):

Some filter function can be called before CRUD operations. So if you have API, then it is possible to authorize user's request and check whether person has grants to execute this operation.

ASP.NET MVC has `Authorize` attribute. It will not allow a request to reach an action protected by this attribute unless the user passes an authorization check. Read more [about authorize attribute here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/policy-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core-a-deep-dive/#:%7E:text=The%20Authorize%20attribute%20enables%20you,if%20the%20user%20is%20authenticated.)

As another way, you can use inheritance or composition (composition is more versatile) and create methods to check eligibility of user when you call your CRUD methods.